# Need help in editing a tab in Woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the name of a tab in product page of woocommerce to a different name.

I am trying to find which PHP file has that particular code but I am unable to do that. Have also used plugins like WhatTheFile (it said the product page is loaded from single-product.php, but I couldn't find the html to edit there) and String Locator and they couldn't help even. Please have a look at this video I made and you will better understand my problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bruhb2n83lhfnp6/Code.mp4?dl=0

I am using G5Plus April theme

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

you can add code like this in functions.php of your theme to customize the product description tab title. For more details, [Link 1](https://gist.github.com/kloon/6435352), [Link 2](http://kb.oboxthemes.com/articles/woocommerce-how-do-i-rename-the-product-description-or-reviews-tabs/)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_customize_tabs', 100, 1 );
function woo_customize_tabs( $tabs ) {
   $tabs['description']['title'] = __( 'More Information' ); // Rename the description tab

   return $tabs;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. But isn't there any other way to edit it directly from source code?

Comment: the source code you mean saying in woocommerce plugin?

Comment: Hi Sunil, apologies for late reply. I mean to edit directly from WordPress editor using the single-product.php file instead of adding the piece of code above in functions.php

There must be a code for that in a file, that's how that tab is being displayed. I am just wondering how to find that code.

Comment: You can find file from the following path in your WordPress directory - "/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/tabs/description.php".